# Vite, sass stylesheets, bulma and darkmode toggle

Tags: sass, media-queries, vite, bulma, darkmode

i have a small static webpage for which i wanted to add darkmode support. As i currently use Bulma i found [this](https://bulma.io/2019/10/15/light-dark-colors/#scheme-variables-for-dark-mode) the following recommended workflow on how to do this.

I now have two `.scss` files in my project:

1. `styles_dark.scss`
2. `styles_light.scss`

Both of which follow the workflow described [here](https://versions.bulma.io/0.7.0/documentation/overview/customize/) to customize sass variables.

My `index.html` looks like this:

```html
<link id="style-light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/styles_light.scss" media="all"/>
<link id="style-dark" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/styles_dark.scss" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"/>
```

Vite will not merge any style sheets with the `media` or `disabled` attribute, as implemted [here](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/6751). Therefore, i add `media="all"` to `styles_light.scss` to have it always active, and `media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"` to `styles_dark.scss` to have it active by default if the user set their preferred color scheme to dark.

Now i can toggle between style sheets by setting a `disabled` attribute and or removing the `media` attribute.

So far so good, this works fine in development, but when bundling for production it will output the following:

```html
<link id="style-light" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,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" media="all"/>
<link id="style-dark" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,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" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"/>
```

Missing the imported bulma information from `@import "../../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass";`.

For now i can workaround this issue by transpiling sass to css beforehand and referencing the css files in my `index.html`, but i am sure there must be a better way to do this, as this will not work nicely with any kind of hot reload.

This is how my `vite.config.js` looks like:

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    base: "./",
    root: "./src",
    build: {
        outDir: "../docs"
    }
})
```